# Multidimensional cube in AZURE

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, ssas, azure-analysis-services, multidimensional-cube

My database is created on **Azure SQL** environment and for **reporting** purpose I want to create **multidimensional cube**. But the problem is **Azure** didn't support **multidimensional cube**. So, Is there any alternative solution to perform **multidimensional cube** on **Azure** environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, Multidimensional models are not supported in Azure PaaS (Platform as a Service). Of course you could always stand up the capability in IaaS (Infrastructure as a Service) by installing your own server.

Tabular models are becoming the trend, and these are supported in [Azure Analysis Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-overview) and Power BI.

[From the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-overview):

> **Built on SQL Server Analysis Services** Azure Analysis Services is compatible with many great features already in SQL Server Analysis
>   Services Enterprise Edition. Azure Analysis Services supports tabular
>   models at the 1200 and higher compatibility levels. Tabular models are
>   relational modeling constructs (model, tables, columns), articulated
>   in tabular metadata object definitions in Tabular Model Scripting
>   Language (TMSL) and Tabular Object Model (TOM) code. Partitions,
>   perspectives, row-level security, bi-directional relationships, and
>   translations are all supported*. *Multidimensional models and
>   PowerPivot for SharePoint are not supported in Azure Analysis
>   Services.*